# declare a forward reference to block typedef?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

in one header file I have something like:

```
typedef void (^MyBlock)(void);
```

I need to use that same exact reference in another header file.

Sure, I can `#import` one header file into another, or include the typedef in the global pre-compiled header, but instead is there a way to forward reference the block typedef?

Comment: You mean in the same way you can forward declare classes and protocols with `@class MyClass;` and `@protocol MyProtocol;` right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not as far as I know, I'd just put it in a shared header and include it where it is needed.

Comment: That's what I did: created a header file which only has the typedef and just #import that header into the other header files.
Thanks!

Comment: Having a header just for the block seems weird. There is nothing else that the block is more 'attached' to that it belongs in a header with?

Comment: It's used by a few different classes: two of which don't know of each other, and one parent that uses those two. Plus, if you think of it as a type, it makes sense to define it in its own header. Since I'm importing this header (the one with the typedef) into other header files, it's nice the typedef-header's scope is so small.